# Can PhoneGap and RoboVm work in harmony?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

The Goal is to make an iOS app using phonegap and java.  When writing phonegap plugins that interact with native code (objective-c) would it be possible instead to make it interact with java when using robovm?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also be interested in some RoboVM-PhoneGap integration.

A 'Simon Robinson' on the [Google RoboVM forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/robovm) offered the following posts regarding using RoboVM output as IOS static libraries:

[RoboVM as a library in Xcode/objc - Aug 13](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robovm/yRXcGvKCwiM/mmGeqUdLDkUJ) (more in-depth explanation)

[RoboVM as a static library - Oct 14](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robovm/8_widRRplwA/xOVykK0tW_kJ)

The following [post](http://www.websector.de/blog/2013/07/25/example-of-a-native-ios-plugin-for-using-phonegap-3) and accompanying [GitHub page](https://github.com/sectore/phonegap3-native-ios-plugin) outline creating PhoneGap IOS plugins (3.0+):

http://www.websector.de/blog/2013/07/25/example-of-a-native-ios-plugin-for-using-phonegap-3

All that is needed is to tie-up the information listed here and RoboVM-PhoneGap plugins should be quite easy to achieve.

Another [PhoneGap IOS plugins post](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/) has some interesting information and code also, however, not all of the tutorial might be applicable to the newer PhoneGap 3.x API.

**FYI, I'll edit this post again to include [some of] the body of information included within the links, ASAP.**